# pytest -k flag with and statement

Tags: pytest

According to the pytest documentation I should be able to use the 'and' expression like this:

```
pytest -k stringexpr # only run tests with names that match the
                     # "string expression", e.g. "MyClass and not method"
                     # will select TestMyClass.test_something
                     # but not TestMyClass.test_method_simple
```

What I tried out was this expression:

```
pytest -v test_file.py -k “TestTest and not test_bad”
```

And the error I got was:

```
ERROR: file not found: and
```

Other variations I have tried that ended in the same failure:

```
pytest -v -k “TestTest and not test_bad”
pytest -v -k “TestTest and not test_bad” test_file.py
```

Finally my pytest version is: `3.0.3`

Comment: is `test_file.py` in the same location from where you are running your py.test command ? Basically the error means, the file `test_file.py` could not be found. Try giving the full path .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `“` and `”` are some weird typographical quotes, instead of the `"` ascii quote used to prevent terminal argument splitting, which means your pytest actually gets four arguments: `“TestTest`, `and`, `not` and `test_bad”`.

Your example works fine for me when using `"` instead.

Comment: Good eye, I got the original commands sent to me through email which I guess had those strange quote types. I should have realized this because it isn't the first time I have done that...